# jQuery Function not doing what is expected

Tags: jquery, html, css, fade

I've just been creating a fadeIn/fadeOut menu with an active class. See code below:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/usj08kqn/2/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


var navItem1 = $('#exemption-nav-1'),
    navItem2 = $('#exemption-nav-2'),
    navItem3 = $('#exemption-nav-3'),
    displayItem1 = $('#exemption-item-1'),
    displayItem2 = $('#exemption-item-2'),
    displayItem3 = $('#exemption-item-3');


function fadeOutAll() {
    (displayItem1).stop().fadeOut('slow', function () {
        navItem1.removeClass('exemption-active');
        (displayItem2).stop().fadeOut('slow', function () {
            navItem2.removeClass('exemption-active');
            (displayItem3).stop().fadeOut('slow', function () {
                navItem3.removeClass('exemption-active');
            });
        });
    });
}

navItem1.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    fadeOutAll(function () {
        navItem1.addClass('exemption-active');
        displayItem1.stop().fadeIn();
    });
});


navItem2.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    fadeOutAll(function () {
        navItem2.addClass('exemption-active');
        displayItem2.stop().fadeIn();
    });
});


navItem3.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    fadeOutAll(function () {
        navItem3.addClass('exemption-active');
        displayItem3.stop().fadeIn();
    });
});
});
```

So I've got this to work without calling that "fadeOutAll" function, but when I actually create that function it all breaks. Any idea?

So all in all I want it to switch between the tabs with the active showing. See this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tur73n14/1/) As you can see this works but I was just trying to condence the code by using a function. Is this possible?

Comment: @hungerstar where?

Comment: I don't get what you mean? They're all unique

Comment: As you can see the first fiddle is with the function that destroys it all. Then the second fiddle is when I go tit all working without a function. No need for a function don't get me wrong it's just nice having neat code

Comment: You're passing a function to `fadeOutAll()` but there are no parameters on fadeOutAll, so it does nothing.

Comment: I see what you mean but I didn't think a function needed params if it's just being called further down the code, Think you could give an example

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/usj08kqn/4/

Comment: No sure what you mean by "if it's being called further down the code" - doesn't matter where it's being called, you're saying "call this with this additional code" and the function is saying "la-la-la I can't hear what you're telling me"

Comment: Ahaha great example :') Thank you I will bare that in mind, is callback just a param that it will listen too, like I don't see the relevance of callBack. But that works perfectly if you could add it as an answer :)

Comment: It's just a parameter name - don't get hung up on it being called callback.  You're passing your extra code, but the function doesn't know about that extra code (as it's not a parameter) and doesn't know what do with it or how to make the extra code run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially your code issue boils down:

```js
function doThis() {
  // do nothing
}

$("#clickme").click(function() {
  doThis(function() {
    alert("clicked");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='button' id='clickme'>click</button>
```

which does ... nothing.

You need to tell `fadeOutAll` (`doThis` above) that it's going to receive an anonymous/inline function and what to do with it:

```js
function doThis(todo) {
  todo();
}

$("#clickme").click(function() {
  doThis(function() {
    alert("clicked");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='button' id='clickme'>click</button>
```

Comment: Once again, Thank you for the help. Cleared up a lot for me :)